# Django Trouble: django.setup() throws "ImportError: No module named 'project_name'"

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, virtualenv

I've been having an issue that I believe can be solved one of 2 ways.  We have a django project I am trying to write some iPython notebooks for teaching purposes and have them in a `tutorials` directory that's one below the root of the project (i.e. `~/tutorials`).

In the beginning of the notebooks I need to import several modules but I encountered a similar problem to the one detailed in this stack overflow question: [Relative imports in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3) , (python couldn't find the paths, even though it could when I ran the notebooks from the root directory)

My solution was to specify the absolute path to the root of the directory in a `path` variable and append it like the following:

```
import sys
path = 'Users/greg/project_name'
sys.path.append(path)
```

That worked and I have been able to make the imports.  However, the problem I am encountering now is that when I run a function that calls get on a Django model like so:

```
Platform.objects.get(name='platform_name').platform_levels.get(db_name=level).id
```

it raises an error from the `python3.4/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py` file saying:

```
AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.
```

Does anybody have any insight into why they aren't being loaded and what I need to do differently?  Please let me know if there's other information that I should provide to help you answer this question.  Thanks!

**Edit**: The suggestion by @albar led to a new error which I think is the root of all the issues.  When I go to run `django.setup()`, it raises an error on this line:

```
mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
```

saying:

```
ImportError: No module named 'project_name'
```

Does it need to be able to import the entire project as a module and if so, how do I tell it how to find it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to [setup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/applications/#django.setup) Django in your script:

```
import django
django.setup()
```

**EDIT**: Before that, you have to define your `settings` module:

```
import os
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myapp.settings'
```

Comment: Thank you for your help so far @albar.  django.setup() is throwing an error that I detailed in the edits.  Any idea how to deal with that?

Comment: Actually, running `django.setup()` after appending the path makes everything work out fine.  The next step would be keeping the path to the project permanently in the `sys.paths` variable instead of having to reload it every time.

Comment: Thank you @albar--I will look into it!

Comment: This post does not answer the question